# Getting the first document of a cursor in MongoDb + C#

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

The whole problem is like so:

> Having a collection of documents in MongoDb, find the first one
>   according to a query and an order.

Since [`FindOne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) in MongoDb does not accept an order, the way to do so is to return a `Cursor` with a `Limit` of one. It is done in `C#` like so:

```
var query = Query<Doc>.EQ(e => e.Deleted, false);
var sortBy = SortBy<Doc>.Ascending(e => e.Date);
var cur = colletion.FindAs<Doc>(query).SetSortOrder(sortBy).SetLimit(1);
```

Then, somehow, I need to take the found document out of the cursor! But how?

The cursor comes with a `Count()` method which returns the number of found documents but it has no means to return the document!? The only way I found is using iteration which is ridiculous!!

```
foreach (var doc in cur)
{
    return doc;
}
return null;
```

Does anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

...

var whatYouAreAfter = cursor.Single();
```