# how to return first element of a MongoCursor?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a cursor which contains at least one element :

```
MongoCursor cursor = oColl.FindAs<CMongoCon>(Query.EQ("isAc", "1"));
```

I would like to return only the first element. Right now I do it this way

```
foreach (CMongoCon job in cursor)
{
  return job;
}
```

Would there be more simple way since I know it's the first element?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
using System.Linq;

...

var whatYouAreAfter = cursor.FirstOrDefault();
```

`cursor.First()` should also work. Just depends what you need.

Inspired heavily from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19492292/2524589

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. However I saw that exact answer to, but I don't have that Single() property even though System.Linq is included

Comment: In that example, they also do .SetSortOrder(sortBy).SetLimit(1) which might return a collection that's valid to use with System.Linq. There might be a method or extension method on the MongoCursor class that returns an ICollection or IEnumerable.

Comment: I don't understand, even though I have system.linq, I cannot use those properties?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use C# fluent API for querying data from mongo? This example works fine on my setup.

```
public Doc GetFirstExistingDocument()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

    return database.GetCollection<Doc>("docs")
        .Find(doc => !doc.Deleted)
        .Sort(Builders<Doc>.Sort.Ascending(doc => doc.Date))
        .First();
}
```